Как определить есть ли NULL в некоем интервале
Дана таблица с тремя полями



group_id
index_old
index_new




1
2
2


1
4
4


1
7
null


1
8
8


1
12
12


2
14
null


2
18
null


2
19
19


2
23
23


2
24
24


2
29
29


3
30
null


3
31
null


3
34
34


3
37
37


3
39
null


3
40
40


3
42
null


3
47
47



Столбец index_new повторяет столбец index_old, но некоторые значения пропущены. Столбец index_old уникален и возрастает. Разница между соседними значениями случайна. group_id уникален и возрастает, количество значений в каждой группе случайно.
Надо получить сгруппированную по group_id таблицу, в которой будет указано (все равно как - лучше булевым значением, но можно и какой-то цифрой) отсутствует ли NULL после минимального не NULL значения в каждой группе в столбце index_new. Другими словами - если в начале группы идут NULL - это нас не беспокоит, дальше появляется не-NULL-значение и нам надо убедится, что после этого значения нету пропущенных.
В примере: В первой группе минимум 2, после него идет NULL вместо 7 - группа ошибочная. Во второй группе сначала идут NULL, минимум 19, после этого NULL не присутствует - подходит. В третьей группе сначала NULL, минимум 34, затем NULL вместо 39 и 42 - ошибка.
Итого в ответе:



group_id
null_flag




1
f


2
t


3
f



Или, в ответе можно так, посчитать количество NULL:



group_id
null_count




1
1


2
0


3
2



Потом я отфильтрую по нулю.
Что я делаю: группирую, беру минимум в каждой группе в index_new, считаю количество объектов бОльших минимума для обоих столбцов и сравниваю количество. Если разница равна нулю - это успех, не равна нулю - неудача.
Можно по-другому, например с помощью EXCEPT или INTERSECT. (Кстати, какой способ лучше - считать и сравнивать количество или пересечь и посчитать, что там осталось?)
Но вопрос вот в чем: во всех моих решениях надо применять сравнение с эталонным столбцом, то есть я не нашел способа, чтобы используя только столбец index_new определить есть ли в нем NULL-значения после определенного значения. Можно ли так сделать? Второй вопрос: какие решения вам видятся более удачными чем мои?
UPD
Пока перечитывал вопрос (кстати, о пользе задавать вопросы), подумал, что можно не сравнивать с количеством в другом столбце, а считать и сравнивать с count(*). Но не уверен, что это будет быстрее.

уникален и возрастает Для таблицы SQL понятие в принципе не существующее, если не указать сортировку. Чай, не Эксель...

какие решения вам видятся более удачными чем мои? Сравнение MAX(index_old) FILTER (index_new IS NULL) и MIN(index_old) FILTER (index_new IS NOT NULL) при (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY index_old). Или даже FIRST_VALUE.

@Akina спасибо за наводку на FILTER, я не знал как он работает, полезно! Логика Ваша тоже отличная, спасибо. Есть вопрос по PARTITION: почему Вы считаете, что партишен, в данной ситуации, лучше GROUP BY, ведь мне нужна таблица не по каждой записи, а по группе? И второй вопрос - зачем Вы применяете ORDER BY внутри окна, насколько я понял как оно работает, это излишне. Или я чего-то не учитываю?

почему Вы считаете, что партишен Это не код, а просто чтобы лишнего не говорить.

@Akina понял, благодарю! Логика мне понятна.

Можно выбрать строки, когда index_new после not null идет null.
Пример:
select *
from(
  select *
    ,lag(index_new,1,index_new)over(partition by group_id order by  index_old) prev_new
  from test
) t
where index_new is  null and prev_new is not null




group_id
index_old
index_new
prev_new




1
7
null
4


3
39
null
37


3
42
null
40



fiddle
Группировка обычная. Если счетчик равен 0, значит группа не включает искомые строки.
select group_id,
  sum(case when index_new is  null and prev_new is not null then 1 else 0 end) cnt
from(
  select *
    ,lag(index_new,1,index_new)over(partition by group_id order by  index_old) prev_new
  from test
) t
group by group_id




group_id
cnt




1
1


2
0


3
2



fiddle
Из двух подряд идущих null будет взят только 1, если это имеет значение.

Интересное решение! Надо только потом каким-то образом оставить только одну строку с группой (а не для каждого null) и вернуть в таблицу те группы, которые без null. Но применение lag - интересная мысль, спасибо.

Группировка самая обычная. Добавил пример в ответ.
